# Entity Framework Database First with proper use of Data Anotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I have one project with `EF` and Code First approach and there using of Data Annotations was straight forward. Now I'm working with Database First and I see that using Data Annotations is more specific so I want to know the right steps to implement it.

The structure of my project that provides Data Access is this:

[image: DataAccess]

In `ModelExtensions` are all my files that I've created to add the Data Annotations to the `DbContextModel.tt` entities.

Here is the structure of one of my files in `ModelExtensions`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DataAccess.ModelExtensions
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MCS_ContentTypesMetaData))]
    public partial class MCS_ContentTypes : BaseEntity
    {

    }

    internal sealed class MCS_ContentTypesMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have several questions here. First - the namespace. Should it be like this `namespace DataAccess.ModelExtensions` or I have to remove the `.ModelExtensions` part. I was looking at a project using DB first and there the namespace was just `DataAccess` not sure why it is needed (if so). Also - Do I need to add some other references to the `DbContextModel.tt` entities? Now I use standard C# classes for this and then rename them to : `public partial class MCS_ContentTypes : BaseEntity`. Do I have to use a special approach for creating those to explicitly expose the connection between the entity and this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The namespace of your extension models must be the same as the namespace of EF auto-generated entity classes - If the namespace of `DbContextModel.tt` entity classes is `DataAccess`, you should set the namespace of your classes to `DataAccess`.

2) I doesn't get your question completely, however in this approach, names of entity classes and your classes must be the same.

The following example shows what it should be. Suppose that EF generates the following entity class for you:

```
namespace YourSolution
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class News
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

So, your partial classes should be like the following:

```
namespace YourSolution
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(NewsAttribs))]
    public partial class News
    {
        // leave it empty.
    }

    public class NewsAttribs
    {            
        // Your attribs will come here.

        [Display(Name = "News title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the news title.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        // and other properties you want...
    }
}
```

So, you doesn't need any `: BaseEntity` inheritance.

Comment: Where should the partial class file be saved?  I expect adding it to `DbContextModel.tt` is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer It's not the matter where you save them. You just need to create them in the same namespace. take a look again in the code example, more precisely.

Comment: I think I got it.  I reuse `namespace MySolution` in the class with the attributes.