# Entity Framework 5.x data annotations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I was using EF 4.x database-first approach. I have the edmx file and it generated the C# class that derived from EntityObject. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that uses the generated class as model. The client validation that validates the required fields worked fine.

Now I moved to EF 5 and used the DbContext generator, it generates the POCO C# class. I found that the required field validation no longer works in EF 5.

I think the problem is that in EF 4.x EntityObject generator, the generated class has `[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]` attribute. However in the EF 5.x POCO class, no data annotation attributes are generated. So the required field information is lost.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the EF 5.x DbContext generator not generate
   `[Required]` annotations from the edmx file?
2. Where is the right place to
   put these data annotations? Should I modify the .tt file to generate
   the [Required] attribute? Or manually write a [MetadataType] partial
   class and define data annotation attributes in a separate
   class?

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't know why. I just know that Db-first approach doesn't add any data annotations to properties.

2) Indeed creating a separate partial class! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871772/1814343) is an example. Because EF will overwrite and regenerate all POCO classes every time you update your model, any changes (also data annotations) to those classes will be lost...

Comment: I found http://t4metadatatemplate.codeplex.com/ template can generate the MetadataType class. However I end up changing the model.tt file to just add [Required] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find this link useful.
[EF Validation](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation)
Simply add Metadata class with the required validation:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))
public partial class User
{
  ...
}
public class UserMetadata
{
    [UserValidate("State")]
    public string State; 
   // etc.
}
```

hope this can help